# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:constance.backends.database app isn't installed correctly

Tags: django, virtualenv

Hi I am setting up my django with virtualenv
When I run python manage.py migrate, I got this error.

> > File "/Users/anh/testRadicards/env/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/constance/backends/database/**init**.py", line 27, in **init**
> >         "The constance.backends.database app isn't installed "
> >     django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The constance.backends.database app isn't installed   correctly. Make sure it's in your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

This is my setup, running with Mac OSX 10.5, on Python 2.7:
  1. cd into my project dir
  2. run virtualenv --no-site-packages env
3. activate my virtualenv with source/env/bin/activate
4. pip install django   (currently 1.7.1)
5. git clone a django project repo called radicards
6. cd into radicards
7. run python.manage.py runserver

(The repo radicards already have a sqlite db setup, so there's no need for migration).

I followed the error code and open settings.py and it include this:

> > INSTALLED_APPS = (
> >         'constance',
> >         'constance.backends.database',
> >         'rd_suit',
> >         'django.contrib.admin',
> >         'django.contrib.auth',
> >         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> >         'django.contrib.sessions',
> >         'django.contrib.messages',
> >         'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> >         'paintstore',
> >         'cards',
> >     )

'Contance.backends.database' is included.  I heard django 1.7 has some issues with unique name error.
What should I do?  To set this up.

Comment: did you run syncdb/migrate after adding constance.backends.database to yur installed apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this setting to your settings.py file:

`CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'`